# 01/01/1970 when the dates are null in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, symfony1, null

I need my showSuccess.php to display an empty string when the birthdays are null, not 01/01/1970.
I tried it with this code, but it does not work:

```
<?php 
if (is_null($client_contact->getBirthday()) == TRUE) {
    echo ""; 
} else {
    echo $client_contact->getBirthday();
}
?>
```

I am working with mysql and symfony
sorry for my English, i'm from Chile

---

I change the function getBirthday() in the class.
Solve it with this:

```
public function getBirthday() {
    if ($this->_get('birthday') == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return date("d-m-Y", strtotime($this->_get('birthday')));
    }
}
```

thank you all for your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

If you `var_dump($client_contact->getBirthday())` do you get NULLs or do you always get a date? If you are using an ORM (Symfony usually uses Doctrine) then it might be the cause of your problem and converts NULLS to 0 timestamp...

It SHOULD NOT do that because NULL != '1970-01-01' and i agree if you, but, if you get that first of all, then look in the doctrine manual why it's doing this. It could be a model configuration problem.

Answer (score 1):

**If it's null or 0, it converts to Epoch (01/01/1970).**

so you can use,

```
if ($client_contact->getBirthday() == "01/01/1970") 
{     
  echo "";  
} else {     
  echo $client_contact->getBirthday();
}
```

or:

```
$bday = $client_contact->getBirthday();

echo ($bday != "01/01/1970" && !is_null($bday)) 
      ? $bday
      : "";
```

But this is not the securest way to do it. you need to use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the class code behind your `$client_contact` object?  If so, in that class check if the birthday value is null.  If so, then return a blank string, else return the date string.  Otherwise, you will be limited to the solution that Tim offered.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if it equals Jan 1, 1970.  While it is unfortunate that any birthday that falls on that date will also get filtered... it seems there isn't another way to make the distinction between that date and unset.

```
<?php
if (($client_contact->getBirthday()) == "01/01/1970") {
    echo ""; 
} else {
    echo $client_contact->getBirthday();
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to configure different date output formats in symfony?  Wouldn't that then break this check?

Comment: I recommend you to use `<?php` instead of `<?`. Because this is disabled on some servers.

Comment: @FrankFarmer You could use Symfony's date format function to always get the output the same as the field would

Comment: @leo Oops, I usually use <?php but for some reason skipped it this time.  Editing to fix it.